# react toggle can't change value separated

Tags: reactjs

I have two toggle like that.How can I change value separated.I click toggle will change the two toggle value.

```
{this.state.frame.map((item, index) => (
           <div className="col-xs-12" key={index}>
        <ToggleButton
            className="pull-left"
            onToggle={this.handleFrameToggleChange.bind(this,index)}
                value={item.show_text == "1" ? true : false/>


        <ToggleButton
                className="pull-left"
                onToggle={this.handleFrameToggleChange.bind(this,index)}
                    value={item.show_text == "1" ? true : false/>
```

functon

```
handleFrameToggleChange(index, event) {
    var frame_setting = this.state.frame;
    frame_setting[index].enabled = frame_setting[index].enabled == "0" ? "1" : "0";
    frame_setting[index].show_text = frame_setting[index].show_text == "0" ? "1" : "0";

    this.setState({
      frame: frame_setting
    });
  }
```

thx alot

Comment: share me source that works. then I'll fix and let you know soon.

Comment: I am not sure, I understand your problem. Do you want to use toggle buttons independently and if you click one of them, the other should not change ? if yes, then how are your toggle buttons differentiated? The way I see it is you are binding both toggle buttons with same same frame in the state. If you change the state of one, it will be reflected in the other as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-bootstrap, you will get a controller with this functionality by default.

```
 <ButtonToolbar>
    <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options" defaultValue={1}>
      <ToggleButton value={1}>Radio 1 (pre-checked)</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={2}>Radio 2</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={3}>Radio 3</ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  </ButtonToolbar>
```

You can get live example from [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/button-group/#btn-groups-checkbox-radio)